# pause a thread to prevent ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating a Swing application to make a Game with. It creates images in random locations off the screen and when they leave the screen I would like to remove them. Please take a look at the code snippet:

```
public void checkTrolls(){ //CAUSES EXCEPTION ERROR WHEN SPRITE EXIT SCREEN
    for(AutomatedSprite a : trolls){
        if(a.getX() < 0 - a.getImage().getWidth())
            trolls.remove(a);
        if(a.getY() < 0 - a.getImage().getWidth())
            trolls.remove(a);
        if(a.getX() > 800)
            trolls.remove(a);
        if(a.getY() > 600)
            trolls.remove(a);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true){
        dodger.update(); //update sprite
        if(trolls.size() != 6){
            trolls.add(new AutomatedSprite("images/troll_face.png"));
        }
        for(Sprite troll : trolls){
            troll.update();         //UPDATES MY SPRITES
        }
        checkTrolls();             //CHECKS TROLLS EXITING THE SCREEN
        repaint();

        for(Sprite troll : trolls){
            System.out.println("X: " + troll.getX());
            System.out.println("Y: " + troll.getY());
        }

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = timeDiff - DELAY;

        if(sleep < 0)
            sleep = 5;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

trolls is a Vector of AutomatedSprites, when they leave the screen I get a ConcurrentModificationException, apparently I can't remove the instances from my vector.

So it seems that I can't remove anything from the vector while the thread is updating all my sprites, is there a way to pause my thread so I can remove the sprite?

P.S: here is the entire class in case I missed something: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JQQ2QD6f)

Comment: Use `synchronized` methods to manipulate the vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot remove from a collection while iterating over it, this is true for a single threaded environment as well as a multithreaded one.  `syncrhonized` will still cause the issue, Thread.sleep too.  Use and Iterator and remove that way.

```
public void checkTrolls(){
    for(Iterator<AutomatedSprite> itr = trolls.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
        AutomatedSpring nextElemnt = itr.next();
        if(youShouldRemoveTheSprite){
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

So here you use the Iterator supplied by your trolls collection.  And you are asking the Iterator to safely remove the object from the collection.

Now if you are executed checkTrolls with multiple threads then you will need to synchronize.  You can do that like this

```
public synchronized void checkTrolls(){ ...
```

***Edit*** based on your recent comment/link.

It isn't so much you assigning the Iterator.next() to a variable, its that you are invoking iterator.next() many times. Each time you invoke `next()` you are moving the iterator to the List's next element.  So at the end of one loop iteration you move the iterator to the 6'th element in the list.  If you were indexing it instead it would look like:

```
   for(Iterator<AutomatedSprite> itr = trolls.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
       if(trolls.get(0).getX() < 0 - trolls.get(1).getImage().getWidth() ||      
                      trolls.get(2).getY() < 0 - trolls.get(3).getImage().getWidth() ||
                       trolls.get(4).getX() > 800 ||
                       trolls.get(5).getY() > 600){
               trolls.remove(trolls.get(5));
       }
```

*Note for this example: indexing at 0,1,2,3,4... is only for demonstration, in practice it would be i = 0; start for loop trolls.get(i++).getX(), trolls.get(i++).getY() and so forth.  If your list was 10,000 you would eventually get a NoSuchElementException*

So for example, if you only have 3 trolls, once you get to the 4th itr.next()  you'll get a NoSuchElementException.  For that reason you'll want to store the next() element in a variable and work on that variable so the itr.hasNext(); returns correctly and the itr.remove() too works correctly.

Comment: I have a while loop iterating through the Vector in my checkTrolls() method but now my game won't even start because it get's the exception right away. 

Do I have to iterate through every other instance of the trolls? if not then I must be having another issue.

Comment: if i do it with a for loop i get a NoSuchElementException :/

Comment: hmmm... wierd but it works. I don't see the difference between using the variable vs using the actual itr.next() method but it stopped the errors.
If you check back can you answer this: wouldn't using the variable just be a substitute for calling itr.next()? if so why when i use itr.next() instead of the variable I get errors?

Thank in advanced!

Comment: @mastrgamr sorry for the late reply.  What do you mean exactly?  Can you give an example of what you did and  I can explain better.

Comment: this: http://pastebin.com/B0qeEAu2

when the iterator is assigned to a variable (AutomatedSprite) there is no exception thrown, but if I just use itr.Next() I get a NoSuchElementException...

Answer (score 2):

In `checkTrolls()` you are removing elements from your `Vector` as you iterate over it.  This will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`

From Vector's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the vector is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

A couple alternatives:

Create a list of elements to remove and remove them after iterating fully.

Use a thread safe `List` implementation such as [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what thread safe is, I'm still learning what threads are and how to utilize them. This is a small game, but if I were making a larger game or application would using a Thread Safe collection affect the program's performance?

Comment: The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` may be too expensive in your case.  I suspect it'd be best to fix this by not removing elements from the list while you are iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

Have your code inside run method in `synchronized` block. synchronized will make sure only one thread executing your code at a time.

```
run(){
synchronized(this){
....your code.
}}
```

You may make `run()` also synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and somewhat naive solution would be too simply synchronize on the `trolls` collection. If you do this, make sure to `yield` in the Animator thread to give your `checkTrolls` function a chance to do processing and cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that in 'checkTrolls' you're trying to modify a vector over which you're iterating.